# Within the eSignature API, is there a way to append text to the default text for "email blurb"?

Tags: docusignapi

**Default text for "email blurb" is something like:**

*recipientFirstName recipientLastName,*

*Please DocuSign sameTextAsEmailSubject*

*Thank You, SalesPersonSmith*

---

**Is there a way to append text to this ? For example I would append the email signature for SalesPersonSmith so something like:**

*SalesPersonSmith*

*sps@company.com*

*p 555.555.1212*

*f 555.555.2323*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to modify the content of the emails that DocuSign sends to recipients:

1. You can use the [emailBlurb](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_emailblurb) inside the envelopeDefinition object.
2. You can modify the [email resources file](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-email-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus) for your account.

Option 1 is limited, as you cannot change everything in the email message. However, you can have each envelope use a different blurb.

Option 2 is account-wide, meaning that it's not per-envelope, but you have more flexibility in the changes you make in the entire email look-and-feel.

Comment: So I believe that I will probably need to review "email resources file" documentation.  Follow-up question just so I understand...I am looking for a way to allow users to include their email signature (name, contact info, etc.) if desired.  Is there a way to append that info to the standard email body for those who wish to include their sig.  ?

Comment: You mean to explain to them how to do that? or allow them functionality in the email to do that without first opening the envelope?
If the former - sure, it's like any other text you can put in the blurb.
But the functionality to adopt a signature is outside if your control, this is done by DocuSign.

Comment: Yes, I was meaning to allow a user/sender to add to the default email body/blurb.  So that their contact info (like the "sig" at the bottom of an email) can be appended to the body/blurb.  So, if I understand correctly, that is not actually doable ?

Comment: You can allow a sender to change the body/blurb. I thought you asked about changing the "adopt a signature" feature

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I was using the term 'signature' to describe the sender contact info that is often found at the end of an email body.    Yes, the body/blurb can be changed by the user but it does replace the body/blurb default text which has, among other items, the recipient's name.   I was hoping to just add to the default text with the sender's contact info.

Comment: Changing the sender's contact info cannot be done per-envelope. You either have to change it permanently, or use different senders. It's based on how you authenticate when you send an envelope.